# Как заменить точку и слеш на тире в строке средствами в javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка следующего вида - `folder/test.mas.inf`
Её необходимо привести в такой формат - `folder-test-mas-inf`

Знаю, что это можно сделать при помощи `replace()`, но вот в регулярных выражения я не силён.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: вот так `/[\-\.]/`

Comment: jQuery не умеет ничего заменять в строках.

Comment: А как на счет javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = 'folder/test.mas.inf';
var result = str.replace(/[\.\/]/g,'-');


console.log( result );
```

если подряд идущие символы (хотя видимо такого нет в исходных данных), следует заменить на единичный минус (то есть `test...test` -> `test-test`), используйте выражение `[\.\-]+`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что несколько точек подряд надо заменять  на один дефис? :)

Comment: @splash58 а потому что сначала тупанул и вместо `g` его написал, и забыл удалить :)

Comment: @teran, а если еще и пробелы заменить на тире, то как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: @MaksimKeyMart добавить пробел в квадратные скобки `[\.\/ ]`, а если и всякие пробельные символы типа табуляции то `\s`

Comment: @teran, спасибо Вам огромное за пояснения. Последний вопрос - если мне нужно оставить в строке только буквы и цифры, а остальные символы и прочие знаки удалить, как поступить в таком случае?

Comment: @MaksimKeyMart если речь про английские буквы, то `/[^\w]+/g`

Comment: @teran а если английские и кириллица?

Comment: @MaksimKeyMart тогда `/[^\wа-я]/giu`

Comment: @teran, спасибо! Исчерпывающий ответ!!!

Comment: @MaksimKeyMart тогда можете [отметить его как Принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @MaksimKeyMart там еще кстати `ё` добавить к `а-я`

Comment: @teran, хорошо. Спасибо еще раз!